# Paginator não funciona quando tem duas tabelas no material angular

Tags: angular

Tenho duas telas de consulta onde carrego os dados em um materialtable com angular e uso o pagination, porém, somente um está funcionando corretamente, aparentemente, o paginator está sempre carregando o último. Preciso fazer com que funciona para as duas tabelas.
HTML tabela 1:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceCfg" matSort>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let cfg">{{cfg.id}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="planta">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Planta</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let cfg">{{cfg.planta}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="linha">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Linha</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let cfg">{{cfg.linha}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="plantaReduzida">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>P.reduzida</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let cfg">{{cfg.plantaReduzida}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="opcoes">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Opções</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let cfg">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" tooltip="Selectionar" (click)="dadosSelecionadoConf(cfg)"><mat-icon>create</mat-icon></button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsCFG"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsCFG;"></tr>

    </mat-table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5]" [showFirstLastButtons]="true"></mat-paginator>
```

HTML tabela 2

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceABV">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Id</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let abv">{{abv.id}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="pProdMes">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>P.ProdMes</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let abv">{{abv.pProdMes}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="nomPlaniControl">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>N. Planilha Control</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let abv">{{abv.nomPlaniControl}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="codItemPlanilha">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Cod. Item planilha</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let abv">{{abv.codItemPlanilha}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="nomeItemControle">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Nome Item Controle</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let abv">{{abv.nomeItemControle}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="opcoes">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Opções</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let abv">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" tooltip="Selectionar" (click)="dadosSelecionadoAbv(abv)"><mat-icon>create</mat-icon></button>  
          </td>
        </ng-container>            

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsABV"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsABV;"></tr>

      </mat-table>
      <mat-paginator [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5]" [showFirstLastButtons]="true"></mat-paginator>
```

e no typescript:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginatorABV: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginatorCFG: MatPaginator;

  constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder,
  private toastr: ToastrService,
  private router: ActivatedRoute,
  private dialog: MatDialog,
  private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
  private route: Router,
  private configuracaoService: ConfiguracoesService,
  private ambevService: AmbevsService,
  private plcService: PLCService,
  private tvService: TVariaveisService,
  private umService: UMsService,
  private historianService: HistoriansService
  ) {
  this.route = route;
  this.getConfiguracao();
  this.getAmbev();
  this.getPLC();
 }

  getAmbev() {
      this.ambevService.getAllAmbev().subscribe(
        (_ambevs: Ambev[]) => {
          this.ambevs = _ambevs;
          this.ambevFiltrada = this.ambevs;
          this.dataSourceABV = new MatTableDataSource(this.ambevs);
          this.dataSourceABV.paginator = this.paginatorABV;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
    }
    getConfiguracao() {
      this.configuracaoService.getAllConfiguracao().subscribe(
        (_configuracoes: Configuracao[]) => {
          this.configuracoes = _configuracoes;
          this.configuracoesFiltradas = this.configuracoes;
          this.dataSourceCfg = new MatTableDataSource(this.configuracoes);
          this.dataSourceCfg.paginator = this.paginatorCFG;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
    }
```

Ao executar somente uma tabela funciona o paginator.
[image: Paginator nao fuciona]
[image: Paginator funciona]
Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: Não sei se isto é possível, pois a diretiva **mat-paginator** espera uma tabela para realizar a paginação, tanto é que não é preciso referenciar a tabela a qual paginação deve ser aplicada, pois isso já é automático. Quando tem duas tabelas o paginator perde a referencia de qual tabela deve paginar.

Answer (score 0):

O **ViewChild** de *paginatorABV* e *paginatorCFG* estão referenciando o mesmo **MatPaginator**.

Quando é assim, é melhor dar nomes as tags por meio de id.

**No HTML ficaria assim:**

```
<mat-paginator #paginatorABV [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5]" [showFirstLastButtons]="true"></mat-paginator>

<mat-paginator #paginatorCFG [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5]" [showFirstLastButtons]="true"></mat-paginator>
```

**No TS ficaria assim:**

```
@ViewChild('paginatorABV') paginatorABV: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild('paginatorCFG') paginatorCFG: MatPaginator;
```

Recomendo-te também a fazer a paginação de acordo com backend.